# How to connect through SSH in Erlang using a PEM key file

Tags: erlang

Using the [ssh](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#connect-3) module in erlang, it is possible to establish a connection to a remote server.

There are several options indicated in such API, but it is unclear to me which one would allow me to establish a connection that is enforced only by authenticating using a .pem file.

For example, using the ssh command in an OS shell, I can connect to my host using this:

```
ssh -c 3des -2 -l root -i MYPERMISSIONFILE.PEM myhost.mydomain.com -p 22
```

In Erlang, the ssh module has a fd option { fd,

```
ssh:start().
ssh:connect("myhost.mydomain.com",22, ???????? ).
```

There are several security options, I beleive the content of the .pem file could be used as one of the security optins, but that would be 1700 characters! There is an option to use a file descriptor [ {fd, } ], but it is unclear to me if that is the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working by copying the pem file using the name `id_rsa` in a folder other than `~/.ssh` (so it doesn't overwrite any keys you have set up already), e.g. `~/keys`, and then passing into `ssh:connect/3` the option `{user_dir, "~/keys"}`. It picks up the renamed pem as the rsa key.